# Ubuntu 20.04 xorg corrupted by conf file

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, xorg.conf

Hello I have PC with Xeon E processor and I am using integrated Intel graphics to drive a VGA display.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04
Everything works fine.
Then I add xorg.conf file, for other reasons, to /etc/X11 ( by default no xorg.conf file is present ) and I get the first screen after the log in is corrupted by yellow vertical lines and/or corrupted icons and eventually a block box is present at half height of the screen.
See here below the incriminated xorg.conf :
Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier "layout"
Screen 0 "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "intel"
Driver "intel"
BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "intel"
Device "intel"
EndSection

and photo of the corrupted screen is here: [image]
If I open terminal or what else looks good but the first screen is always a bit corrupted.
If I change the background image , the new background appears without vertical lines. If I go back to the original background image that is still corrupted with vertical lines.
I am sure the corruption is because of the xorg.conf file but how can I fix the situation ? I need the xorg.conf file because I want xorg.conf to use only the internal integrated intel graphics and not other graphics cards/drivers that will be present.

Do you have any idea of what the cause could be ?

thank you

Comment: Hei, it appears to be a bug on Ubuntu 20.04 only. I tried same sequence with Ubuntu 18.04 and problem does not happen